# Having some problems with sql (Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am coding a small php project an have some problems with sql.
I know what the failure message tells me but I can't find the problem in the code i wrote.

```
        $cart_product_id = 2;
        $cart_product_amount = 1;
        $new_order_id = 478478;
        $userid = 1;
        $cart_product_price_stk = 15;
        $product_shipping_comment = "no_comment";

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`productid`, `amount`, `order_id`, `userid`, `price_pro_stück`, `user_shipping_comment`) VALUES (:productid, :amount, :order_id, :userid, :price_pro_stück, :user_shipping_comment);");
        $result2 = $statement->execute(array('productid' => $cart_product_id, 'amount' => $cart_product_amount, 'order_id' => $new_order_id, 'userid' => $userid, 'price_pro_stück' => $cart_product_price_stk, 'user_shipping_comment' => $product_shipping_comment));
```

Please help me i am freaking out right now lol

Comment: I think it has problems with non-standard characters, `price_pro_stück` may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Php has problems with the paceholders if you use the german ü

changing it from :price_pro_stück to :price_pro_stueck will resolve the problem

```
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`productid`, `amount`, `order_id`, `userid`, `price_pro_stück`, `user_shipping_comment`) VALUES (:productid, :amount, :order_id, :userid, :price_pro_stueck, :user_shipping_comment);");
    $result2 = $statement->execute(array('productid' => $cart_product_id, 'amount' => $cart_product_amount, 'order_id' => $new_order_id, 'userid' => $userid, 'price_pro_stueck' => $cart_product_price_stk, 'user_shipping_comment' => $product_shipping_comment));
```